# DELETE with a percentage on total count

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I want to delete 10% of rows, is there a query to do this?

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE conditions LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE conditions) * 0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply return the total amount of filtered rows, calculate through php and use that value as a limit in my DELETE query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE conditions");
$int = reset(mysql_fetch_array($query));
$int = round($int * 0.1);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl WHERE conditions LIMIT {$int}");
```

I'm not sure if DELETE allows an advanced query such as this one:

```
DELETE FROM (   SELECT h2.id
                FROM (  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
                        FROM tbl
                        WHERE conditions) AS h
                JOIN (  SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
                        FROM tbl, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS vars
                        WHERE conditions) AS h2
                ON '1'
                WHERE rownum < total * 0.1) AS h3
```

Comment: Probably really farfetced, but maybe above query would do that? :)

Comment: i will stich with old lovely php way

Answer (score 4):

If you only need *roughly* 10% of rows, in no particular order, this should do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE RAND() <= 0.1
```

However, I don't recommend using it on very large data sets due to the overhead of generating random numbers.

Comment: Although, on the other hand, the more rows, the closer to 10% the percentage might be.

Comment: Yup. For small rowsets, it's not very accurate. I'd imagine anything above roughly 100 rows should be fine though.

Comment: NO i have some conditionns and some ORDER BY

Comment: You can apply both of those: `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE RAND() <= 0.1 AND tbl.id IN (SELECT tbl.id FROM tbl WHERE ... ORDER BY ...)`

Comment: now that's smart. but i believe with large dataset it's pretty performance-killer

Comment: Yeah, on a large (read: >500k) data set it'll have poor performance.